# Windows 7 goes into standby while Syncback is working on a profile

Tags: standby, syncback

Normally windows shouldn't go into standby mode until the profile has finished copying the files, but on this computer it does and afterwards a get a whole bunch of error message regarding the failed backup. What can i do?

Using fresh installed Windows 7 and Syncback Freeware Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not on High Performance Power Plan, see:
[How to Select a Power Plan in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/774-power-plan-select.html)

Comment: kind of dirty, but better than nothing :) thanks :)